# Django: No module named blog

Tags: django

Well, pardon for asking such a question. But searching didn't help me.

I did:

```
django-admin.py startproject mysite
./manage.py startapp blog
```

Well, now I can see:

```
michael@ubuntu:~/PycharmProjects/mysite$ ls -l
total 12
drwxrwxr-x 2 michael michael 4096 Oct  2 08:22 blog
-rwxr-xr-x 1 michael michael  249 Oct  2 08:14 manage.py
drwxrwxr-x 2 michael michael 4096 Oct  2 08:26 mysite
```

In settings.py I added my blog:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (

    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'mysite.blog',
```

Then mentioned SQlite:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': '/var/db/django.db',
        'USER': '',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': '',
        'PORT': '',
    }
}
```

Then I edited models.py

from django.db import models:

```
class BlogPost(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 150)
    body = models.TextField()
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField()
```

Well, when I do:

```
./manage.py syncdb
```

I get:

```
Error: No module named blog
```

Could you help me cope with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> sqlite3.OperationalError: unable to open database file

indicates a permission problem. make sure you have necessary permissions in `/var/db/`

Answer (score 4):

In `INSTALLED_APPS` add `blog` instead of `'mysite.blog'`.

Comment: Well, it seems to have helped a bit. But there is another problem at once: sqlite3.OperationalError: unable to open database file

Comment: Check you have enough permissions to write to your DB file `/var/db/django.db`

Answer (score 3):

In INSTALLED_APPS, you need to have just 'blog' instead of 'mysite.blog'. That should fix your problem.